# Working with Python Files in Azure Function - Read Only File System

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions

New to Azure functions, but looking to utilize a Function in an ADF pipeline to call out to a third party and write the json back for ingestion.

However, I receive Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:
...
"/home/site/wwwroot/AzureFunctionFileTest/**init**.py", line 10, in main with open('test.json', 'w') as file.

My script is below:

```
logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

logging.info('opening file')

with open('test.json', 'rb') as file:
    logging.info('creating data')
    data = "Hello world"
    logging.info('writing file')
    file.write(data)

return func.HttpResponse(f"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully with {data}.")
```

Is there an Azure Function config that I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current directory is indeed read-only. Use `/tmp` for temporary files (for example, `open('/tmp/test.json', ...)`. For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#temporary-files.

Comment: All the searching in the world and I couldn't find that one article you linked to. That helps out tremendously. 
I'm assuming if working with a dataframe I could also use 
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile as temp:
    df.to_csv(temp.name, ...)

and then upload to blob?

Comment: @MattPieper Yes, `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` should also work.

Comment: Be aware: /tmp appears to be (from experienced behavior - couldn't find doc) a tmpfs, therefore you're writing to memory, and may cause memory pressure, if the amount of data written is large.

Comment: Thank you. very helpful. I also missed this in the documentation!