# Is possible to save a temporaly file in a Azure Function Linux Consuption Plan in Python?

Tags: python, file, permissions, save, azure-functions

first of all sorry for my English. I have an Azure Function Linux Consuption Plan using Python and I need to generate an html, transform to pdf using wkhtmltopdf and send it by email.

```
 #generate temporally pdf
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="binary/wkhtmltopdf")
pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, 'report.pdf',configuration=config, options={})

#read pdf and transform to Bytes
with open('report.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

#encode bytes
encoded = base64.b64encode(data).decode()

#Send Email
EmailSendData.sendEmail(html_content,encoded,spanish_month)
```

Code is running ok in my local development but when I deploy the function and execute the code I am getting an error saying:

```
Result: Failure Exception: OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error: Loading pages (1/6) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% [==============================> ] 50% [============================================================] 100% QPainter::begin(): Returned false Error: Unable to write to destination
```

I think that error is reported because for any reason write permission is not available. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where you want to stored to? The temporaly file is create by the body of your function?

Comment: I´m sorry, I try in in local storage. I also try to save that file in azure blob storage but i can`t because to upload it you need to create that file locally

Comment: I am not sure about the meaning of your second sentence...Can you explain?: 'I cannot save in azure blob storage neither because the file must be created also in local storage'

Comment: I`m sorry, I have edited the comment.

Comment: Why need to create files locally first? Just save data as stream then upload is ok.

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement. Do you want to upload something to storage and then face some error?

Comment: It is because html to pdf library converts that html code to a file. 
    `config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="binary/wkhtmltopdf")
    pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, 'report.pdf',configuration=config, options={})

    #read pdf and transform to Bytes
    with open('report.pdf', 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()`

Comment: The error comes from this part? Hi, you can add the code in your question. It is very important when you ask some question.:)

Comment: Yes, error comes when pdf library try to save the pdf file.`pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, 'report.pdf',configuration=config, options={}`

Comment: Please add the python code to your quetion. It is very important. Do you know how to edit your question?

Comment: This answer may help you: [Working with Python Files in Azure Function - Read Only File System](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63096767/6027154)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `tempfile.gettempdir()` method returns a temporary folder, **which on Linux is `/tmp`**. Your application can **use this directory to store temporary files** generated and used by your functions during execution.

So use `/tmp/report.pdf` as the file directory to save temporary file.

```
with open('/tmp/report.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#temporary-files).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Program works in azure function! I`m going to edit my question whit the correct code

Answer (score 3):

Final correct code:

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="binary/wkhtmltopdf")

local_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'report.pdf')
logger.info(tempfile.gettempdir())

pdfkit.from_string(pdf_content, local_path,configuration=config, options={})
```