# Is it possible to write video or audio file in current directory using moviepy in Azure Functions as azure functions have read only access

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, moviepy

**Is it possible to write video or audio file in current directory using moviepy in Azure Functions as azure functions have read only access?**

I want to use moviepy to concatenate videos in azure functions, even though it is running locally but after it is deployed to azure functions its giving error that functions have read only access.

I used below code:

```
final_clip.write_videofile('finalvideo.mp4',codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a')
```

And when I used the following codes:

```
final_clip.write_videofile('/tmp/finalvideo.mp4',codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile='/tmp/temp-audio.m4a')
```

[image: console logs for above codes]

[image: Expended Logs]

Comment: You might be able to use Azure Files to provide a read-write file system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations#mount-file-shares

Answer (score 0):

The current directory is indeed read-only. Use `/tmp` for temporary files (for example, `open('/tmp/test.json', ...)`)

Below is the sample code for creating temporary files in temporary directory.

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import tempfile
from os import listdir

#---
   tempFilePath = tempfile.gettempdir()
   fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
   fp.write(b'Hello world!')
   filesDirListInTemp = listdir(tempFilePath)
```

[image]

For complete information over temporary files refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux,application-level#temporary-files).

Here is the example code for importing Audio File in HTTP triggered function using Movie py.

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import tempfile
import imageio
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip



speech_key="<speech service key>"
service_region="<speech service region>"
temp_file_path = tempfile.gettempdir() + "/result.wav"
text = 'hello, this is a test'

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

    auto_detect_source_language_config = speechsdk.languageconfig.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig()

    speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(
        speech_config=speech_config, auto_detect_source_language_config=auto_detect_source_language_config,audio_config=None)

    result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get();
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
            stream = speechsdk.AudioDataStream(result)
            stream.save_to_wav_file(temp_file_path)
    
    myclip = AudioFileClip(temp_file_path)

    return func.HttpResponse(str(myclip.duration))
```

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66057088) thread for further details.

Comment: i am getting problem in line:
final_clip.write_videofile('/tmp/finalvideo.mp4',codec='libx264', audio_codec='aac', temp_audiofile='/tmp/temp-audio.m4a')

Comment: I am getting this Error
Exception while executing function: Functions.videoStitch Result: Failure
Exception: OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file /tmp/e34e8650558448ed8d2f1ee45f838c3b.mp4:

  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 228, in ffmpeg_write_video
    writer.write_frame(frame)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 180, in write_frame
    raise IOError(error)