# How to access a medium size static file in Azure function?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a simple Function written in Python which will be triggered using HTTP.

I will be needing a static file which will be about 50 MB.
I will need it everytime my function is called.

I tried looking for a solution in Azure portal but could not find any.

What is the solution?

Comment: Can't you embed the file as a manifest-resource-stream in your published assembly (or however your publish/deploy system handles content files) - and extract it to `%TEMP%` on-demand?

Comment: @Dai i m creating a python function. sorry but i dont understand much from ur comment. can u please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were using C#/.NET.

Comment: What is the file and how does your Python code use it? (is it a database file, a CSV file, an executable compiled/binary program? etc?)

Comment: it is a Vector DB file created using Spotify Annoy. Whenever my function is called i ll be needing the db file.

Comment: See here for how to use temporary files in Azure Functions in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265669/is-possible-to-save-a-temporaly-file-in-a-azure-function-linux-consuption-plan-i